# Sharepoint list: permission levels

Tags: list, permissions, list-view

I'm planning to create a SharePoint list which holds user requests. List elements are created by me, the affected user is listed as requestor in a people column.

I want to design strict permissions for 3 different user groups:

1. requesting user: can **see** only his/her requests
2. data privacy department: can **see** all entries
3. me & other SPO owners: can see/edit/manage all items

Using different views seems to be an option but that requires views 1. and 2. to be public which therefor can be changed by the end user.

Answer (score 0):

There are some item level permissions settings that could help you here. If you go to list settings > Advanced Settings > Item level permissions, you can set ordinary users to only be able to read and edit items that they have created.

[image]

For requirement 3, as long as those users have a higher permission level that contains the "Cancel Checkout permission", then they will be able to see and edit all items.

As for requirement 2, you may be able to achieve this with a custom permission level that has Cancel Checkout permission but does not have edit or delete item permissions (I don't know if this will work). If this doesn't work, content approval or good auditing could help, even if they decided to edit or delete an item.